# Most efficient or idiomatic way to test singleton list contents in Haskell?

Tags: performance, list, haskell, comparison

This question is strictly academic for me right now, but I can see it having practical application someday. Working my way through Haskell self-education, I've successfully built the infinite list of prime numbers. One portion of it is this function:

```
isPrime n
    | n < 2                         = False
    | head (primeFactorsOf n) == n  = True
    | otherwise                     = False
```

Where `primeFactorsOf` returns the list of a number's prime factors in ascending order. `1` is not prime, so a prime number `n`'s prime factors are the singleton list `[n]`. The second guard case could therefore be replaced with this:

```
    | primeFactorsOf n == [n]       = True
```

Is one of these more efficient than the other? If not, is one better style? My hunch is that calling head and comparing two simple numbers is faster than calling cons and comparing two singleton lists, so what I've already got would be best. But if there's no difference, I think the alternative looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: I don't think that this is a part of your algorithm where the speed really matters and GHC might optimize a bit anyway. That said I think the first is fine. Or you can write a `smallestPrimFactor` function that just uses patter-matching on `primeFactorsOf n` to make it a bit more read- and understandable.

Comment: Just a side note. `| foo = bar | xyz = True | otherwise = False` is perhaps better written as `| foo = bar | otherwise = xyz`.

Comment: @n.m. Oddly, that's something that I would have done by default in any imperative language, yet it took me about 30 seconds to figure out what you could possibly mean! Step 1 of Haskell was "unlearn everything." I'm sure step 3 is going to be "unlearn step 1."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If speed is really important, the only way to be sure is to benchmark it, for which I'd suggest [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).  Which provides better performance is not entirely clear.  If `primeFactorsOf` gets inlined, then the compiler may notice that you're comparing two lists in the second case and automatically remove the boxing.  Or it may not, in which case your hunch is likely correct.

As to which is better style, the second form is.  Partial functions like `head` are best avoided most of the time.  However, perhaps you can do even better?

```
isPrime n = case primeFactorsOf n of
  [n'] | n == n' && n >= 2 -> True
  _ -> False
```

or you could put the check for `n >= 2` on the outside.  Or, if you know that `primeFactorsOf` returns an empty list for `n < 2`, it can be omitted entirely.

Edit: golfed to

```
isPrime n = case primeFactorsOf n of
  [_] -> n > 1
  _ -> False
```

Comment: I would say `case primeFactorsOf n of { [_] -> True; _ -> False }`.

Comment: The list is only empty for 1 and -1. Negative numbers can have prime factors, and zero has the infinite set, so the <2 test is pertinent. I'm honestly not sure what's going on in yours, John... is that somehow a pattern match plus a guard, allowing fallthrough? Anyway, changing n.m.'s first case to `[_] -> n > 1` looks like the cleanest solution!

Comment: @TheodoreLiefGannon you're exactly correct, it's a pattern match and a guard.  If either fails, the case falls through to the next statement, which is a wildcard so it will always match.

Answer (score 0):

(*total rewrite*) Yes your first variant is better. It is equivalent to

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && head fs == n
    where
       fs = primeFactorsOf n
```

the second variant is

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && fs == [n]
    where
       fs = primeFactorsOf n
```

which is equivalent to

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && head fs == n && null (tail fs)
    where
       fs = primeFactorsOf n
```

For composites both behave the same, but for primes the latter variant will perform the extra test unnecessarily.

We might be tempted to "simplify and improve" the last variant as

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && null (tail fs)
    where
       fs = primeFactorsOf n
```

that will spare a number comparison operation for primes, but for composites it will actually force the calculation of a second factor of `n`, unnecessarily, which might be quite costly (e.g. `n = 2 * p` with `p` some big prime). Your first variant will find the first factor and immediately return `False`.

---

To correct this, we could perform manual "fusing" of `isPrime` with `primeFactors`. Assuming it is defined as

```
primeFactors n = factor n primes
    where
        factor n (p:ps) 
            | p*p > n        = [n]
            | n `mod` p == 0 = p : factor (n `div` p) (p:ps)
            | otherwise      = factor n ps
```

fused with the last version, it becomes

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && hasOneFactor n primes  -- (null . tail . primeFactorsOf)
    where                                   --   == hasOneFactor
        hasOneFactor n (p:ps) 
            | p*p > n        = True
            | n `mod` p == 0 = False
            | otherwise      = hasOneFactor n ps
```

which is now the most efficient code here. It can be further re-written as (also, `rem` is faster than `mod`)

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && hasOneFactor primes    -- no need to pass `n` around
    where
        hasOneFactor (p:ps) = p*p > n ||
                              ( n `rem` p /= 0 && 
                                hasOneFactor ps )
```

or

```
isPrime n = n > 1 && foldr (\p r-> p*p > n || (rem n p /= 0 && r))
                           undefined primes
```

Comment: how exactly does the second variant not compare two singleton lists?  Looks to me like that's exactly what happens.  The compiler may optimize it out, but it might not (it didn't when I checked, but YMMV depending on context).

Comment: yes, but if you're comparing two lists, you first have to check if the outer constructor is `[]` or `:`.  Which is it for `[n]`?  Better not be `[]`, which only leaves cons.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand where I'm not being clear.  I'm saying that in comparing `primeFactorsOf n == [n]`, the RHS has an extra indirection (`[n] === n:[] === cons n []`, which is less efficient than `head (primeFactorsOf n) == n` (as the OP suggests), because in the latter case the RHS has one less indirection and only the LHS needs to be deconstructed.  It's probably not a significant concern except in a really tight loop though.  And I would expect that GHC could remove it for you in some cases.

Comment: I suspect the OP was doing the same thing I was, and when saying "comparing two singleton lists" only consider the `True` case (the perf concerns apply to both cases WLOG).